# Python singular value decomposition on images for noise filtering

Tags: python, pca, svd

I am trying to create a PCA script that goes through a set of images and decomposes them into PC's that are sorted by power/weight. As far as I understand you want to do `M = U*S*V.T` which I have done below. I cut off the array at N which is the filter that removes all lower PC's. but it does not seem to be working at all and gives back gibberish that is clearly not the PC's. Am I misunderstanding the math?

```
def PCA(cube_array, PCA_N=False, cutoff=1, verbatim=0):
    cube_shape_z, cube_shape_x, cube_shape_y = cube_array.shape
    n = 1
    M = cube_array.reshape(cube_array.shape[0],-1)


    U, s, Vt = np.linalg.svd(M, full_matrices=False)
    V = Vt.T
    S = np.diag(s)
    N = cutoff
    Mhat = np.dot(U[:, :N], np.dot(S[:N, :N], 
    V[:,:N].T)).reshape(cube_array.shape)
    return Mhat
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use Scikit Learn [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) instead of doing the math yourself. [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html) you can see an application of PCA in image processing.

Comment: I've tried that, also using the noise filtering example here. But I am not quite sure how this works either. I ran it on my `23x300x300` image and it gives back n_components_=7. where did the rest go? I even tried `a = PCA(n_components=23).fit(data)` but 7 again.

Answer (score 0):

The principal components are just the corresponding first N columns of V.

What you computed is the best rank N approximation of the matrix M in the 2-norm and Frobenius norm.

Comment: So id I want to visualise the components I plot the rows of V.T?
How about throwing it back together using say the first 3 components and seeing how the data looks like after that?

Comment: You can do a projection on the first 3 components and get 3 dimensional vectors and use whatever technology you have to visualize 3 dimensions.

Comment: Ok, so once I have the frames I want to take out I just subtract them from.the input data? To filter unwanted noise

Comment: i have no idea what you are referring to as frame.

Comment: The PC images that are noise and not signal.